# SQL combining of a COUNT with a WHERE in single query

Tags: sql

Here is the data, call it table T

```
A   B
--  --
1   14
2   15
3   16
4   1
4   3
4   6
4   9
4   12
4   15
```

I would like to get the value of A that has only one value and a B value of 15.
There are two rows where B=15 but there are 6 rows where A=4 and only one row where A=2.

So the correct SQL should return me the 2.

I have tried this but it returns both rows.

```
select A from T group by A,B having Count(A) = 1 and B = 15
```

This similarly fails:

```
select A from T where B = 15 group by A having count( A ) = 1
```

Comment: I should note that `group by A, T` would fail with a syntax error.  I assume you mean `group by A, B`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: actually in Postgres this would be correct. You can use a table reference anywhere where you can use a column - it simply means "all columns of the row as an anonymous record type" - which still wouldn't make sense, but it would not result in an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select A
from T
group by A
having Count(A) = 1 and Max(B) = 15;
```

Your problem seems to be that you are grouping by both columns.  You only want to group by `A`.

Admittedly, your query has `group by A, T`, but I think that is a typo, based on the described behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the count of B after grouping by A.

```
select A 
from T 
group by A
having Count(B) = 1 and max(B) = 15
```

Comment: This answer and the above both work on this data, yet one counts on B and the other on A. Perhaps it doesn't matter which one you count on.

Comment: i think you should count B's not A's.

Comment: they both work and I added a 4, 17 just to check the max still works and it does.

Comment: They do but I can only accept one answer and you both seemed to answer at exactly the same time. I accepted the other one because he needs the reputation more than you do...